# npm login error "Public registration is not allowed"?

Tags: npm

When I run `npm login` I got the 403 error  "Public registration is not allowed", but this is my package, I can login from the web page https://www.npmjs.com, so what could be the reason?

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmmirror.com/-/user/org.couchdb.user:qiulang2000 - 
[FORBIDDEN] Public registration is not allowed
```

Answer (score 5):

I figure that out because I used npm mirror https://registry.npm.taobao.org/,

```
% npm login
npm notice Log in on https://registry.npm.taobao.org/
Username: qiulang2000
Password:
Email: (this IS public) xxxxx
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.5.0 -> 8.15.1
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.15.1
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.15.1 to update!
npm notice
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmmirror.com/-
/user/org.couchdb.user:qiulang2000 - [FORBIDDEN] Public registration is not allowed
```

After I changed it back to `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` I can npm login